Can't remotely view remote KDE Plasma desktop via VNC or Remote Desktop
I have a remote machine running Ubuntu 22.04, KDE Plasma is the machine's DE. I want to view it remotely. I can do so with RealVNC Server running on the remote machine, but the nice people have discontinued their free Home plan, which allows for 5 remote devices, and replaced it with the Lite plan which only allows 3 remote devices. I am managing four devices so one of them, the remote KDE Plasma one, is orphaned. So I want to find a non-RealVNC way to view and control the user's desktop. Using TightVNC, UltraVNC, or Remote Desktop (xrdp) servers on the remote machine does allow me to connect to it, but they create their own desktops for the sessions, and I can't see the user's desktop. So far, only RealVNC shows the user's desktop.
Long intro, sorry. So my question is: How to configure UltraVNC server, or TightVNC server, or xrdp to show the user's desktop — and not create a new desktop — when connected to remotely? Thank you!

I don't use KDE, so I can't tell you the details. You may try x11vnc. It may need editing a config fine after installation. Another alternative is Anydesk. It is not open source, but free for non commercial use.
